# How is windows task scheduler able to run interactive programs?

Tags: windows

In latter versions of windows (I am using windows 10), windows services run in session 0 isolation which as far as I understand doesn't belong to any logged in user and means they cannot interact with users. If windows task scheduler runs as a service how is able to run interactive programs and the current logged logged in user? Is Microsoft using some back door API or is the something that I can do in services that I write myself?